# Title does not show in new post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I registered a new post type. But in the admin menu when I want to add a new post the title bar does not show.

The code is:

```
  $label = array(
     'name' => __( 'نمونه کار ها' ),
     'singular_name' => __( 'نمونه کار' ),
   );
   $arg = array(
     'labels' => $label,
     'public' => true,
     'has_archive' => true,
     'menu_position' => 10,
     'supports' =>array(
       'author',
       'editor',
       'page-attributes',
       'revisions' ,
       'comments',
       'custom-fields',
       'trackbacks',
       'excerpt',
       'thumbnail',
     ),
     'taxonomies' => array('portfolio_cat','portfolio_tag'),
   );
   register_post_type("haportfolio",$arg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `title` in `supports`

```
$arg = array(
     'labels' => $label,
     'public' => true,
     'has_archive' => true,
     'menu_position' => 10,
     'supports' =>array(
       'title',
       'author',
       'editor',
       'page-attributes',
       'revisions' ,
       'comments',
       'custom-fields',
       'trackbacks',
       'excerpt',
       'thumbnail',
     ),
```